# Circuit for Read/Write RAM Control Signals

Tags: digital-logic, buffer, ram, timing

I have the following architecture of an 8-bit bus / RAM interface where the bus can read from and write to the SRAM:

[image: RAM Circuit]

There are two 74LS245 8-bit bi-directional buffers, with there direction input hardwired to the according logic level to read or write from bus/RAM. The enable signals for these buffers are active low. The SRAM chip is an 2K x 8bit Renesas 6116 IC.

It is a very simple design. When reading from RAM, OE is low and the RAM OUT buffer is enabled. Likewise when writing to RAM, OE is high, RAM IN buffer is enabled and the WE pulse occurs. All seems ok. I am happy with the WE logic but not sure how to best implement the OE logic.

My question is about the control logic for the RAM OE signal. Ram in is an active high input which initiates the writing to RAM sequence. This disables the RAM outputs (OE is high) and the 74LS04N inverts this signal to enable the RAM IN buffer (this IC input will go low). There will be a small  propagation delay for the inverter to switch meaning the RAM output and the buffer output won't be driving lines at the same time (RAM output should be disabled before the buffer gets enabled).

However when the write is complete and the RAM in signal goes low, the RAM OE signal will immediately go high before the inverter switches off the RAM IN buffer's outputs, meaning there will be line contention by these two chips for a very small time period (max 15ns according to the 74LS04N datasheet).

Will this circuit work ok or how are RAM writes actually implemented? I'm sure this is a common problem designers face, but it's my first time implementing RAM interfaces in hardware. Probably just a case of designing better (and more complex) logic to prevent this from happening is my thought?

Comment: The 245 is bi-directional. So is SRAM data bus. Your system is unknown, but it seems pointless to put two bi-directional buffers to a RAM chip that already has a bi-directional bus. It might help if you tell where exactly you want to connect the SRAM chip.

Comment: @Justme This circuit is part of an 8-bit CPU consisting of TTL logic ICs. The reason I have placed 2 74LS245s like this is to simplify the logic for the control unit of the CPU. This way I have one signal for RAM in and one other signal for RAM out. All this logic I am trying to develop is to handle the writing and reading to/from RAM. I could have used one 245 but I thought this may make the logic simpler? So the SRAM chip is essentially connected to the 8-bit bus as shown in the image through these buffers.

Comment: It might be a personal preference, but to me the simplest interface is what almost all CPUs use for SRAM - they use separate read and write signals, and one of them simply controls the direction for a 245. If there even is one. But as the RAM already has three state IO, I don't see what use two separate buffers help, why use 245s at all?

Comment: Actually the RAM in buffer has some logic placed between the bus and it's inputs so it can be changed to modify RAM without running an actual write cycle. And probably should have shown on the diagram, but there are 8 LEDs connected to the RAM IO lines so you can visually see what each memory location holds. I see what you mean, there actually is no need for the 245s at all. Except I want someway of doing this what I mentioned here.

Comment: `Actually the RAM in buffer has some logic placed between the bus and its inputs` doesn't explain the difference having the buffer makes. I can't parse `so it can be changed to modify RAM without running an actual write cycle` to any avail, starting with not knowing what *it* might be changed.

Comment: Note that for busses or signals that could be tri-stated (that is, float), it is generally considered good design practice to provide pull ups on all those signals so that the bus is in a deterministic state when it is not being driven.  With your setup, you have two tri-state busses to have to contend with.  This is another good reason to eliminate the '245 buffers.